# linux + perl + replace any WORD in file with special characters with condition

Tags: linux, bash, perl, shell-script, ksh

Example1  work fine when I want to replace OLD_TEXT with NEW_TEXT ( its replace also all special characters as $@^%)(_+`:; etc ..)

```
  example1

  export OLD_TEXT='$$OLD_WORD$$'
  export NEW_TEXT='$$NEW_WORD$$'


  perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/\Q$ENV{OLD_TEXT}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_TEXT}$2/g' file
```

on example2

I add the "[[:^alnum:]]" in the perl syntax in order to ignore TEXT that start with alpha numeric characters or end with alpha numric characters

but as all see it doesn't work why?

remark: alpha numric characters means numbers OR [a-z][A-Z]

Real Example

```
 #example2 on LINUX machine:


  more file

  ABC$$OLD_WORD$$ABC
  $$OLD_WORD$$
```

.

```
   perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(\Q|[[:^alnum:]])$ENV{OLD_TEXT}(\E|[[:^alnum:]])/$1$ENV{NEW_TEXT}$2/g' file

     $$NEW_WORD$$ABC$$$NEW_WORD$$$$$NEW_WORD$$OLD_$$NEW_WORD$$WORD$$$NEW_WORD$$$$$NEW_WORD$$ABC
```

.

Example what I should get:

```
  more file


  ABC$$OLD_WORD$$ABC
  $$NEW_WORD$$
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `[^[:alnum:]]`, not `[[:^alnum:]]`. `[:alnum:]` is the POSIX character class being referred to. The brackets *surrounding* the brackets of that character class are the scope that you want to be within.

Comment: hi Chris - I change it but still its not replace the word : perl -pe 'next if /^#/; s/(\Q|[^[:alnum:]])$ENV{OLD_TEXT}(\E|[^[:alnum:]])/$1$ENV{NEW_TEXT}$2/g' file